# Различия между категорией состояния и безличным глаголом

Tags: морфология

Как отличить категорию состояния от безличного глагола в безличных предложениях?

Смекнулось. Посветлело в окне. Вам не видать таких событий. Мне было весело вдохнуть ночную свежесть. Нигде не дышится вольней родных лугов, родных полей.

Comment: Приведите примеры, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/kategoriia-sostoianiia.html  http://webkonspect.com/?id=15460&labelid=202207&room=profile

Comment: Относительно группы слов, соотносимых с наречием, всё ясно. Затруднение представляют слова, сходные с безличными глаголами. Как их различать?

Comment: Смекнулось - это как по-русски? Может, смеркалось?

Comment: В Малом академическом словаре есть и такое слово, и такая форма. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/64790/%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F

Comment: Владимир, в комментарии Людмилы подразумевалось, что Вы пропустили букву "р": смеркнуться — _сме́рклось и **сме́ркнулось**, сме́рклась..._ "**Смеркнулось**, стало темно" (М. Пришвин).

Answer (score 1):

```
 Как отличить категорию состояния от безличного глагола в 
 безличных предложениях?
```

А как их можно перепутать? С наречием и кратким прилагательным — да, можно: Его лицо (каково?) холодно. — краткое прилагательное.

Он смотрит (как?) холодно. — наречие.

Ему (**каково?**) холодно. — **категория состояния (состояние человека)**.

**Глагол отвечает на вопрос Что делает? Что делается?**

Безличные глаголы употребляются:

•   в неопределенной, или начальной, форме. Примеры: *светлеть, холодать, смеркаться.*

•   в условном, или сослагательном, наклонении, при этом безличный глагол "сопровождается" частичкой "бы". Примеры: *потеплело бы, рассвело бы.*

•   в изъявительном наклонении. Тут уже больше вариантов: так, безличные глаголы могут быть: а) в форме 3-го лица наст. вр. и будущ. вр., в единств. числе: *нездоровится, не сидится, холодает;* б) в форме ср. рода прош. вр.: *смеркалось, теплело, темнело*.

При этом нужно помнить, что **при безличном глаголе никогда нет подлежащего.** Это важно, ибо иногда безличными глаголами могут выступать личные: *Поляна пахнет земляникой* (личный глагол, есть подлежащее). *На поляне пахнет земляникой.* — **безличный глагол, нет подлежащего и быть не может, действие самопроизвольно.**